# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring

I'm running Tomcat and everything seems to work fine until I actually try bringing up the page in Postman, then I get this error (full stack trace):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'stopController' defined in file [C:\Users\Scott Meyer\metrolink-project\target\classes\metrolink\rest\mvc\StopController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [metrolink.core.services.StopService]: : No qualifying bean of type [metrolink.core.services.StopService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [metrolink.core.services.StopService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:751)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [metrolink.core.services.StopService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
... 36 more

Dec 03, 2014 1:42:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet mvc-dispatcher
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [metrolink.core.services.StopService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1009)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here's my business-config File:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="metrolink.core.repositories.jpa"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlite:metrolink.db" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="metrolink.core.entities"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="metrolink.core.services" />

    </beans>
```

And the relevant code:

```
package metrolink.core.services.impl;

import etc...

@Service
@Transactional
public class StopServiceImpl implements StopService {

@Autowired
private StopRepo stopRepo;

@Override
public Stop find(int stopId) {
    Stop stop = stopRepo.find(stopId);
    if( stop == null ) {
        throw new StopDoesNotExistException();
    }
    return stop;
}

@Override
public Stop findByStopName(String name) {
    return stopRepo.findStopByName(name);
}

@Override
public StopList findAllStops() {
    return new StopList (stopRepo.findAllStops());
}
}
```

and

```
package metrolink.rest.mvc;

import etc...

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/stops")
public class StopController {

private StopService stopService;

@Autowired
public StopController(StopService stopService) {
    this.stopService = stopService;
}

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<StopListResource> findAllStops(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name) {
    StopList list = null;
    if(name == null) {
        list = stopService.findAllStops();
    } else {
        Stop stop = stopService.findByStopName(name);
        if(stop == null) {
            list = new StopList(new ArrayList<Stop>());
        } else {
            list = new StopList(Arrays.asList(stop));
        }
    }
    StopListResource res = new StopListResourceAsm().toResource(list);
    return new ResponseEntity<StopListResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/{stopId}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<StopResource> getStop( @PathVariable int stopId ) {
    Stop stop = stopService.find(stopId);
    if(stop != null) {
        StopResource res = new StopResourceAsm().toResource(stop);
        return new ResponseEntity<StopResource>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<StopResource>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<StopListResource> findAllStops() {
    StopList stopList = stopService.findAllStops();
    StopListResource stopListRes = new StopListResourceAsm().toResource(stopList);
    return new ResponseEntity<StopListResource>(stopListRes, HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/business-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include only the following line. Remove all other context:component-scan entries.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="metrolink.core"/>
```

Comment: That worked, only now I'm getting "The requested resource is not available."  I posted my web.xml above in case that has something to do with it.

Comment: This is the backend for a web application.  I try to bring it up in a browser and that's the error message I get.  I seems to look fine server side, no errors, nothing in the log.